# random() Integer saved in sqlite database changes value everytime

Tags: objective-c, random

I'm writing an application wich saves entries in the internal sqlite db  with a primary key and makes an `LocalNotification` with this key as the userInfo.

But if I get the key from the `LocalNotification` and search for its entry in the db, I find nothing. Then i changed the `Interface` that i see the key in a `Label` and have noticed that the key is changing after every application start.

So I try to make another "key"column and saved a

```
NSInteger *randomNR = (NSInteger*)random()
```

into it. But this number is also changing everytime! So can I copy the actual number of the `random()` method and save this to the db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not making an `NSInteger` from `random()` correctly. `random(3)` returns a `long`. You can't simply cast a long into an `NSInteger *` and get the value you want.

You may be confusing `NSInteger` with an object. `NSInteger`s are primitive data types and don't *need* to be pointers like Cocoa classes. You probably want to use:

```
NSInteger randomNR = (NSInteger) random();
NSInteger *randomNRPtr = &randomNR;    // If you really _do_ want a pointer
```

Comment: oops...I'm such a fool... a cast like (NSInteger*) aNSNumber has caused this failure...